# 2010 People and Groups increase number of users displayed per page

Tags: 2010, view

In 2010 is there a way of changing the default view of a "Peoples and Groups" to be more than 30?

Comment: Is given solution works for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click > Site Settings > People and Groups (under User and Permissions).

Check and confirm the default view. Click > Settings > List Settings.

On the List Settings page select your default view (example: Detail View).

Find **Item Limit** and increase the number of items to display. Default it should be 30.

Comment: Under Settings I have "Group Settings", "View Group Permissions" and "Make Default Group" but no List Settings...perhaps I don't have enough powers?

Comment: check if you are login to the site as site collection admin account

Comment: Ah no I only have admin rights to my site, I don't have admin rights to the site collection :(

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need to access the site collection using Site Collection Admin account.

Then on root site go to,

1. **Site Settings** --> **People and Groups** --> From Menu, **List Settings** --> Down, you will find **Detail** and **List** Views.
2. Select Your current view & find **Item Limit** settings on the page.
3. Expand the **Item Limit** & replace the value from **30** to **100**

Now you are done with it.

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Is above given information helps you?

Comment: Under Settings I have "Group Settings", "View Group Permissions" and "Make Default Group" but no List Settings...perhaps I don't have enough powers?

Comment: Are you on a root site collection? as i have already mentioned that It will be available under site collection only